# Why bash process substitution works with jdk11 version of keytool but not with jdk17?

Tags: java, bash, keytool, java-17, process-substitution

I test the following on jdk11:

```bash
/opt/jdk11/bin/keytool -printcert -v -file <(cat mycert.pem)
```

And prints the certificate details as expected.

But if I do the same with jdk17 version of keytool I get an exception:

```bash
/opt/jdk17/bin/keytool -printcert -v -file <(cat mycert.pem)
```

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Illegal seek
java.io.IOException: Illegal seek
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.position0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.position(FileInputStream.java:363)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readAllBytes(FileInputStream.java:281)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.generateCertificates(Main.java:2804)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.printCertFromStream(Main.java:2762)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doPrintCert(Main.java:2961)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1286)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:415)
    at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:408)
```

But the following works:

```bash
/opt/jdk17/bin/keytool -printcert -v -file mycert.pem
```

Clearly process substitution does not work with jdk17 keytool. My question is the following:

Is there a bash workaround to fix this?

Should this be considered a bug of jdk17 keytool and if yes what is the code that I should avoid in order to make my java programs friendly to bash process substitution?

Comment: I don't think it's technically a bug, since you're not providing a regular file argument but a pipe argument (which the shell creates for you) and the keytool expects a file. A workaround would be to write the certificate to a temporary file (I assume that `cat mycert.pem` is a placeholder for the actual command, as there wouldn't be a reason for the process substitution otherwise).

Comment: Having run `strace` on both versions of `keytool`, I found process substitution uses file descriptors while  `/opt/jdk17/bin/keytool -printcert -v -file mycert.pem` points to the real file. Also, `jdk11-keytool` uses `libstdc++.so.6` library where in `jdk17-keytool` onwards use `librt.so.1` library. I'm no C-lang expert but these are the differences I could find with `strace`

Comment: I tried reading from `stdin` like `cat /tmp/test.pem | strace /usr/lib/jvm/java-18-openjdk-18.0.1.0.10-2.rolling.el7.x86_64/bin/keytool -printcert -v` & it worked on both `jdk-11` & `jdk-17` onwards..

Comment: It's an optimized specialization of readAllBytes [added to FileInputStream at jdk-17-ga](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/da4dfde71a176d2b8401782178e854d4c924eba1) and FileInputStream is only used for `-file x` so yes if you omit `-file` and use stdin from a pipe it uses System.in which is apparently unaffected @harshavmb

Comment: This seems like a fundamental flaw in the process substitution syntax:  It creates a named pipe, so it will only work if the receiving program never attempts a seek.  And for nearly all programs, there is no way to be certain the binary will not attempt a seek.  Even if you have the code, future implementations may do it differently, which is what happened here.